# C++ SetCurrentConsoleFontEx doesn't fail, but doesn't set the font either

Tags: c++, winapi, fonts, console, locale

On my home system which is Win7x64 English/Nordic, this function works fine, but on the work system which is Win10x64 Japanese, it doesn't fail, but font font remains unchanged.

On both systems it says *"Font was set to 'Consolas'."*

On my home system, by checking the console window's properties, it is indeed Consolas, but on the work system it is selected to Raster Fonts: SimSun-ExtB, so it feels like something is getting ignored or passed wrongly.
I have no idea why. 
Does anyone have any experience with this?

**This is the code I use to set the font:**

```
inline void SetFont(const std::string& font = "Consolas") {
    CONSOLE_FONT_INFOEX cfi;
    cfi.cbSize = sizeof(cfi);
    //cfi.nFont = 0;
    cfi.dwFontSize.X = 8;                   // Width of each character in the font
    cfi.dwFontSize.Y = 16;                  // Height
    cfi.FontFamily = FF_DONTCARE;
    cfi.FontWeight = FW_NORMAL;

    std::wstring widestr = std::wstring(font.begin(), font.end());
    std::wcscpy(cfi.FaceName, widestr.c_str());

    if (SetCurrentConsoleFontEx(h_Console, FALSE, &cfi) == FALSE) {
        Test("Could not set the font to '"+font+"'.");
    }
    else { Test("Font was set to '" + font + "'."); }

    SetConsoleTextAttribute(h_Console, m_TextColorNow);
}
```

Comment: Use `GetCurrentConsoleFontEx` to fill `cfi` structure, and just change the font name. Also change the function to `SetFont(const std::wstring& fontname = L"Consolas"`)` and `wcscpy` the font directly.

Comment: @BarmakShemirani Thanks, I'll give it a try and get back to you :)

Comment: @BarmakShemirani Sadly, this doesn't seem to have an effect on the Japanese machine. Do you know if a system's locale settings can cause such a thing? I can change the font in the console window properties just fine..

Comment: It works on my Windows 10 (English, Build 17763). Some Windows 10 updates have bugs, maybe that's the case. Is `h_Console` defined as `GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE)`?